# How to point to a different project.json location in a .NET Core PCL?

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild, asp.net-core, dnx

Say you have a .NET Core PCL that's supposed to compile for multiple platforms. Since csproj-based projects only support compiling for one platform at a time, you can't have a shared `project.json`. Thus, your directory structure looks like this:

```
LibFoo
|
---- LibFoo.csproj
|
---- Platforms
     |
     ---- net45
     |    |
     |    ---- project.json
     |
     ---- netcore451
          |
          ---- project.json
```

You also have two MSBuild target platforms: `Net45` and `NetCore451`. When building for `Net45` you want to include the project file in `Platforms/net45`, and for `NetCore451` (which is Windows 8.1, by the way) you want to include the one in `netcore451`.

How would you go about implementing this in MSBuild? Here is what I have so far:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <ProjectJsonRoot>Platforms\$(Platform.ToLower())</ProjectJsonRoot>
  <ProjectJson>$(ProjectJsonRoot)\project.json</ProjectJson>
</PropertyGroup>

<!-- Now $(ProjectJson) is set to the project.json location,
     what do I do to 'register' it with the compiler? -->
```

**TL;DR:** How would you set the `project.json` to a different location from your csproj file, if it isn't in the same location as it?

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the [AutoMapper repo](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/tree/develop/src) you can see how Jimmy Bogard have structured the code, where csproj files are targeting "older" project types.

Comment: Thanks for answering! Unfortunately, I don't think this answers my question. The repo you linked to uses multiple csproj files to target different platforms. My question is asking how to use multiple `project.json` files to achieve this affect.

Answer (score 0):

Well, unfortunately it looks as if you have to create a custom MSBuild task to do this:

https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/6169

I ended up just going with @Nyegaard's answer and writing multiple csproj files.